# How to switch on the "auto-build" option in VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

What option (where it is located in VS2008 menu) is need to be switched on in order VS2008 compile and build solution before launch (native C++ project)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.  The setting "On Run, when projects are out of date" is relevant.  You'll probably want "Always build".  The setting for the next one has "Do not launch" as the only sane option.